# RuntimeException: Can't create handler in onPreExecute()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runtimeexception

I'm getting a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`, and, since I know, that means that I'm trying to make some UI modification in a thread that is not the UI thread. What is worrying me is that I'm getting the exception inside the `onPreExecute()` of an `AsyncTask`, wich IS the UI thread:

```
public class CreateDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private static final String TAG = "CreateDatabaseTask";

    private SQLiteHelper helper;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private Context context;

    public CreateDatabaseTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        helper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);  // <--- Just here!

        if (!helper.checkExists()) {
            dialog.setMessage("Iniciando por primera vez...");
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) throws SQLException {
    ...
    }

}
```

I'm calling the `CreateDatabaseTask` constructor from the `public void onUpgrade(...)` in my custom `SQLiteOpenHelper` class:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {
            deleteDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CreateDatabaseTask task = new CreateDatabaseTask(context);  //<--- I'm calling the constructor here
        task.execute();
    }
```

So, is this `AsyncTask` cheating me or did I missunderstand something?

Comment: What you are passing `CreateDatabaseTask` in this call Constructor ? and from where executing   AsyncTask ?

Comment: can you post your full errace trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProgressDialog` gets `Context` in the `Constructor` but you used `this` inside your onPreExecute. Instead you should write `YourActivity.this`(*respective name of your activity*)

#### Note:

Cause of this error may be trying to display an application `dialog` through a `Context` that is not an `Activity`

---

*Try this way*

```
public class CreateDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

private static final String TAG = "CreateDatabaseTask";

private SQLiteHelper helper;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

private Context context;

public CreateDatabaseTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this); //context should be instance of the Activity  
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    helper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
    

    if (!helper.checkExists()) {
        dialog.setMessage("Iniciando por primera vez...");
        dialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) throws SQLException {
...
}

}
```

Comment: This class is in its own file, so I have an `No enclosing instance of the type MyActivity is accessible in scope`. Anyway, I solved it moving the `dialog = new ProgressDialog...` into the constructor, but I want to know what I was doing wrong :)

Comment: cause of this error may be trying to display an application **dialog** through a **Context** that is not an **Activity**.

Comment: You are right, the Context was not an activity :) I suggest you to edit your answer so I can accept it.